# How to display current fetch url and what is going on with my State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, momentjs

I have an React Native App that is connected to a PostgresDB via ExpressJS. I have a fetch call that holds an url with two params, one of them is getting changed by setState.

Is there a way that I can show (console.log) the current fetch url inside my app when it runs?

```
`http://myip/api/hours/daydata/${realDate}/${userid}`
```

realDate is getting changed by this.setState on a button click.

I would like to console.log the url so I can see the new Date that is set in the url because I have the problem that my component doesnt rerender on the first button click. The date changes in the frontend but the component doesnt render the data that my fetchcall provides it gets displayed when I press the button twice so I am always one day off.

For example I am seeing the data for the 10.10.2019. When I press the back button the date changes inside the calendar but the data stays (data from 10.10.2019) - when I click the button again I should see the data from 08.10.2019 but I get the data from 09.10.2019 (1 day off).

One thing I noticed is that the buttons dont render on first click but choosing a date directly in the calendar does change everything correctly. Here you can see the 2 different calls maybe you see what could be wrong.

```
  dateBackHandler = () => {
    console.log("Current Date FIRST :", this.state.date); // Here I get the date from today

    const newDate = Moment(this.state.date)
      .subtract(1, "d")
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    console.log("NEW DATE BEFORE SETSTATE & FETCHDATA " + newDate);
 // newDate gives me yesterdays date which is correct

    this.setState({ date: newDate }); // I am setting newDate to be the date

    console.log("Current Date SECOND After setState : ", this.state.date); 
// this log should now be yesterdays date because I changed it but somehow this date is todaysdate again

    this.fetchData(); // in here is the fetchcall that should work with yesterdays date.
  };
```

Inside my calendar (datetimepicker) the setState call works tho :

```
onDateChange={date => {
              this.setState({ date: date });
              this.fetchData();
            }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: pass your fetch function as a callback (second argument) of the `this.setState` because it is asynchronous

Comment: Thanks ! It works now just have to adjust some things. Dziekuje;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setState`is an asynchronous function. So you have to execute the dependent function in `callback` function.

```
onDateChange={date => {
              this.setState({ date: date }, () => {
                  this.fetchData();
              });              
            }}
```